# How to keep images in memory when using SliverList?

Tags: flutter

I'm rendering a long list of items with an image included for each item. When scrolling through the list the images will load but then disappear as soon as they scroll off screen so that when you scroll back they have to load again. How can I keep them cached in memory so that they appear immediately when scrolling?

```dart
    SliverList.builder(
      itemCount: meals.length,
      addAutomaticKeepAlives: true,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
          child: _mealLog(meals[index]),
        );
      },
    )

    Widget _mealLog(Meal meal) {
        return Column(children: [Text(meal.label), CachedNetworkImage(
            imageUrl: meal.imageUrl,
            width: 60,
            height: 60,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            placeholder: (context, url) => placeholder(),
            errorWidget: (context, error, stackTrace) {
                return placeholder();
            },
            ),
        ]);
    }
```